# alphabetically sort a hash table in javascript

Tags: javascript, sorting, hashtable

I am trying to sort a hashtable (originally called "resultVal") alphabetically in javascript.

```
// initializing an array with all the keys. //
var keys = [];
// populating it with all the keys in the hashtable. //
for (var key in resultVal) {
    if (resultVal.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        keys.push(key);
    }
}
// Alphabetically sorting the array populated with hash table keys. //
keys.sort();
var temp = {};

for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    var key = keys[i];
    var value = resultVal[key];
    if (key != "") {
        temp[key].push(value);
    }
}
```

My issue is with the last statement :-

```
temp[key].push(value);
```

What I am doing is, sort the keys alphabetically and re-feed the key and its respective values into a temp hashtable..."temp".

The push statement isn't being recognized. can anyone help?

Comment: Since object properties are not sorted, there really is no need to do all of this. If you need to access the values in a sorted ordered at some point, extract and sort the keys later on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`temp` is defined as an object, not an array. There's no need to `push()` onto it:

```
temp[key] = value;
```

Comment: thanks man, worked! Could you explain why exactly it is not necessary to push into an object as opposed to an array. Because when I created the hashtable I merged two separate arrays and used the push functionality. I apologize for the noobish=ness.

Comment: The value stored at `temp[key]` is not an array. You would have to define an array object in that position of the temp array if you want to push onto it.

Comment: Also, be aware of the fact that properties in JS might have different position (depending on JS engine/browser and its name). So if you need specific positions of props, always use an array.

Comment: in my code, the value is a list of dates aka a 1 dimensional array with dates. hence i thought I had to push them into the temp of key position. however now it makes sense! thanks all!